# Редирект 301 в php коде с html/ на html без слеш

Tags: php

Есть код в котором генериться ссылка.html, но она также доступна как ссылка.html/
Помогите сделать редирект 301 прямо в этом коде:

```
                $check_str = $message['id'].'-'.cpu(stripslashes($message['title'])).'.html';
            if($check_str != $message_id_str || count($_GET['cat']) != 2)
                {
                redirect301($path.'messages/'.$check_str);
                exit();
                }
```

Comment: Почему именно в php? mod_rewrite или редирект в конфиге nginx мне кажется более логичным инструментом

Comment: Потому что необходимо это только для этих генерирующихся ссылок.

Comment: Видимо я не очень точно понимаю проблему. Вопрос написан недостаточно подробно. Какова ваша цель? Вы хотите чтобы был редирект с ссылок `ссылка.html/` на `ссылка.html`?

Comment: Да правильно. потому что образуются дубли страниц

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяйте на наличие слеша в конце ссылки и если он есть тогда делайте редирект

```
$url_parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (substr($url_parts['path'], -1) === '/') {
    $redirect_url = $url_parts['path'];
    if (!empty($url_parts['query'])) {
         $redirect_url .= '?' . $url_parts['query']
    }
    redirect301($redirect_url);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: А куда вставить это или что заменить?

Comment: @sander Как все запущено :( Немного изменил ответ, поскольку в коде, который вы привели в вопросе я не уверен. Единственное на что сделал ставку, так это на наличие функции `redirect301()`. Пробуйте заменить код в вопросе на код в ответе. Также можете поднять его выше по коду до первых вызовов `require` или `include`.

Comment: Согласен. не разбираюсь в этом.

Comment: Помог предыдущий код     $url_parts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                if (substr($url_parts['path'], -1) === '/') {
                redirect301($path.'messages/'.$check_str);
                exit();
                    }

Answer (score 0):

Это просто, используйте `HEADER`, вот [документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: ".$path.'messages/'.$check_str); 
exit();
```

Comment: не сработало ((, ссылка доступна и с "/" и без

Comment: Правильно сделал? заменил это                 redirect301($path.'messages/'.$check_str);
                exit();

Comment: @sander - да замените эту строку redirect301(.... , должно работать без проблем, а вы уверенны что $path.'messages/'.$check_str - это корректный URL  ?

Comment: Не уверен, не разбираюсь в php. Не срабатывает